# TicTacToe minimax algo with Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm implementing minimax algorithm in Java. I've followed Codding Trains tutorial. The issue is that the AI always chooses next available spot, not the best one.

game.put() puts players (or blank spot) id on board in given point.

board is a variable of game class, it's two dimensional array of bytes.

game.checkForWin() returns 0 if game is still on, -1 if nobody won and there are no possible moves (tie), 1 if AI won and 2 if Player won.

```
    public Point bestMove(){
        int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Point move = null;

        for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
                if (board[i][j] == blank){
                    game.put(ai_id, new Point(i,j));
                    int score = minimax(false);
                    game.put(blank, new Point(i,j));
                    if(score > bestScore){
                        bestScore = score;
                        move = new Point(i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return move;
    }

    public int minimax(boolean ai_turn){
        int state = game.checkForWin();
        if (state!=0){ // If game ended
            if(state == -1){
                return 0; //TIE
            }
            if( state == ai_id){
                return 1; //AI wins
            }
            return -1; //Player wins
        }

        int bestScore = 0;

        if(ai_turn){
            bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
                    if (board[i][j] == blank){
                        game.put(ai_id, new Point(i,j));
                        int score = minimax(false);
                        game.put(blank, new Point(i,j));
                        bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
                    if (board[i][j] == blank){
                        game.put(player_id, new Point(i,j));
                        int score = minimax(true);
                        game.put(blank, new Point(i,j));
                        bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
```

EDIT:
I rewrote whole game code and this function algorithm works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You do not check for the value `2`  if player has won. Insteat you check about `-1` what is wrong.

Comment: I check if state is not 0 then it can only be -1, 1, or 2. If it's not -1 and not 1 I think I don't have to check if it's 2 because it's impossible it's something else. Nevertheless I added if statement checking if state is 2 and it still chooses next available spot.

Comment: Your program works for me. Please provide an example position where the AI choose the wrong move.

Comment: Even the first move was wrong - it just piked first available spot. I re wrote game code and it now works. There must have been bug (I may have wrote it unnecessarily complicated)

Comment: How can you know the first move is wrong? All moves lead to an tie.

Comment: If i pick position (0,0) then the algorithm should pick the most optimal position (1,1), and mine was picking (0,1). But as I wrote it was a bug in game code, not in 'AI' code.

Comment: Ah ok, nice that you found the bug :)